# API Post Python

Tags: python, api, post

I am trying to make a post request within the Matchbook API.
I have logged in and I got below "Session- Tocken":

```
{"session-token":"xxxx_b0b8a6f22a82396b6afcfa344f3022","user-id":xx685,"role":"USER"}
```

However, I am not sure how to make the post request. See below code used:

```
headers = {"session-token" : "xxxx_b0b8a6f22a82396b6afcfa344f3022"}
r = requests.post('https://api.matchbook.com/edge/rest/reports/v1/offers/current/?odds-type=DECIMAL&exchange-type=binary&currency=EUR, headers = headers')
print r.text
```

Below is the error message that I got. It does not make sense to me because I logged in successfully and got the above session-token in response.

```
{"errors":[{"messages":["You are not authorised to access this resource. Login to continue."]}]}
```

Am I properly indicating the session-token in the header information of the post request?

Comment: You should pass `headers` as to the post method: `requests.post(url, headers=headers)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `headers` argument in `post` function.

```
headers = {"session-token" : "xxxx_b0b8a6f22a82396b6afcfa344f3022"}
response = requests.post('https://api.matchbook.com/edge/rest/reports/v1/offers/current/?odds-type=DECIMAL&exchange-type=binary&currency=EUR', headers=headers)
```

also if you need to get an `json` response, just call `json()` function on `response` variable.

something like `response.json()`

Comment: @MichaelYusko It works as you indicated. However, now I have found an "unexpected error" because I am not sure how to add the json data to the post request. Below is what I found in the Matchbook documentation:  JSON
{
  "odds-type":"DECIMAL",
  "exchange-type":"back-lay",
  "offers":
    [{
        "runner-id":401525949430009,
        "side":"back",
        "odds": 2.4,
        "stake": 5.0
    }
]}  How can I add this information to the post request? As per the documentation, it has to be added as an array.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, do something like this, `requests.post('myexample.com', data={'name': 'My name'}).json()`